# Regular expression in python is not returning the desired result

Tags: python, regex

Suppose that I have a string consisting of different sentences. I expect to remove the part that begins with `It was formerly known as`  until the end of this sentence. I want to stop cleaning until it reaches `. Withey Limited`. If it is not the case, it ends cleaning until `. It`.

```
import re
txt = 'It was formerly known as A. Withey & Black Limited. Withey Limited delivers many things. It has a facility in the UK, including many branches.'
out = re.sub("\s*It was formerly known as [\w\d\s@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:\.]+" + "(?=(. Withey Limited |. It))","", txt)
```

This code returns `. It has a facility in the UK, including many branches.'` which is not my expected outcome. My expected outcome is as follows:

```
Withey Limited delivers many things. It has a facility in the UK, including many branches.
```

How can I adjust my regular expression to reach this outcome? And why is it behaving like this?

Comment: This is not really related to your problem, but you should probably escape the `.` in `. It` and `. Withey Limited`. As I understand it, you want to match a literal period, but this will match any character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+?` to make the matching non-greedy.

```py
out = re.sub(r"\s*It was formerly known as [\w\d\s@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:\.]+?\. " + "(?=(Withey Limited|It))","", txt)
```